# Connecting android application to a web server database

Tags: android, xml, json, communication

I'm doing some research on how to pull information from a MySQL DB to display information in an application but I'm wondering what would be a good way to do this? Right now I'm thinking something like...

ANDROID APP <--> HTTP (display XML to pull and display on app) <--> DB Server.

I read about JSON and some other ways to do this, but I just was wondering if anyone knows the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, yes, that's how you would do it.  JSON is easy to handle on the Android side, so it may be a good choice for you. There are nuances to doing this type of access well on the Android platform that you should be aware of.  There is a [video on the Android Developer's site](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html) that covers design patterns for accessing REST services from Android.   Look for Android REST client applications in the video list.

Answer (score 3):

Yes i would use php to connect and output it as json which is easily parseable by android

You can use this
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```